# Defined global variables with 3 php pages

Tags: php

Just a strange thing have 3 pages in php where are I define global variables with **define()** i uploaded in a XAMPP server.

The main page has this required pages

```
// defined password and username costants;     
require_once('config.php'); 

// defined other new constants and it use also password and username constant.
require_once('http_post.php');
```

**Config.php** and **http_post.php** has no reference (required) to each others.

I was asking to myself how http_post can take password and username defined in config.php without reference, in one XAMPP installation it works all, htt_post.php can retrieve username and password variable (localhost) from config but when I upload to a server always with XAMPP (no more localhost for me) http_post.php cannot see username and password in config.php. How is possible? What changed? Some particular behaviour of localhost? Two PHP pages referred by a main page are in some way connected?

Thx a lot

Comment: Can you share your code? (Changing the username and password of course).

Comment: i put a echo in php and in http_post.php the variable remain so PASSWORD and USERNAME not with the assigned values...

Comment: Can you please share what you have inside `config.php` and `http_post.php` with us?

Answer (score -1):

Use localStorage or cookies. In php you can have it use something like this:

```
echo "<script>localStorage.username = " . $username . "</script>";
```